# Number of subarrays with sum less than or equal a given 'k'

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I know a O(n2) soln, can it be done in a better way, as the limit of no of elements in the array is huge is <=100,000

Comment: Are the elements in the array guaranteed to be nonnegative?

Comment: Yes elements are non-negative !!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is a O(n lgn) algorithm if all elements are non-negative.

1. Define `p[i]` be the sum of `p[0..i]` (We call it prefix sum)
2. For each `i`: Binary search maximum `j` such that `p[j] - p[i-1] <= k`, add `j-i+1` to the counter

Total complexity is `O(n) + O(n lgn) = O(n lgn)`

Why it works, is because for each `i`, we are trying to find the maximum range starting from `i` such that the sum of this range is <= k.

Let this range be `[i..j]`,  as all elements are non-negative, so `[i..i], [i..i+1], [i..i+2] ... [i..j]` are all sub-array which sum is <= k, there are total `j-i+1`  of them.

We find such range for each `i`, and keep adding the number of sub-array starting from `i` which sum <= k

Comment: I suspect there is maybe some tricks using two-pointers in O(n) to do similar things though...

Comment: you've correctly pointed out, no. of sub arrays = j - i + 1. but the explanation for this logic is wrong. if what you say is considered,you'll end up having multiple repetitions and missing some. The correct explanation would be: for range [i...j], new instances would be: [ j ], [j-1..j], [j-2...j], ....., [i+1...j], [i...j] ex: say for k =7 and lis = [1,2,3]: i=1, j=1: [1] --> 1 i=1, j=2: [1,2] --> [2], [1,2] i=1, j=3: [1,2,3] --> [3], [2,3], [1,2,3]

Comment: That's right, posted some code for [a two-pointer O(n) solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69928291/12279039) as well

Answer (score 1):

Outflak explained the algorithm for a linear time solution of the problem provided the elements are non-negative quite well.

I came here with the same question as the OP and got my answer after reading outflak's answer, but since there was no code I had to write it up myself.

Hence, I'm adding some Python code along with some explanation for future readers:

```py
left, right, runSum, count = 0, 0, 0, 0

nums = [10,11,30,1009,13]
limit = 35
# Expected answer - 5 ([10], [11], [10,11], [30], [13])

while right < len(nums):
    runSum += nums[right]
    while runSum > limit:
        runSum -= nums[left]
        left += 1
    count += right - left + 1
    right += 1

print(count)
```

```
>>> 5
```

Just to reiterate:

1. We're making use of a sliding window, with `left` and `right` being our two pointers.
   `runSum` is the accumulated running sum and `count` is our answer.
2. At each step, we expand our window by adding `nums[right]` to `runSum`.
3. Then as long as runSum is greater than our allowed limit, we shrink the window by subtracting from the left side of the window, i.e. `nums[left]`.
4. Finally, `right - left + 1` gives us the 'size' of our current valid window, which we add to our `count` at every step.

Comment: Such crisp explanation, thanks @Ayush !

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by shole, if all elements are non-negative, you can indeed use a "two pointer" technique to solve this problem in O(n).

Basically you have two pointers left and right, initialized both at 0.
You increment the right pointer, and keep track of current sum : while current sum inside the sliding window is <= k, you keep incrementing "right". Once the sum of elements inside the window is > k, then you increment left pointer, to reduce the sum inside the window.
Each time the window is valid and left=i and right=j, you can say there are j-i more subarrays that are valid (the subarrays beginning at k [i, j] and finishing at j) and which were not counted before.